# 7-Zip script needed for extraction of zips in hierarchy, from a specified root folder

Tags: 7-zip

Recently I've been looking for a 7-Zip script for a batch file that will let me scan all the .zip files in a hierarchy and unzip their contents where zips are found. I've found this example here:

```
>>>> CD "(required directory)"
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
        FOR %%X in (*.zip) DO (
            "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X"
        )
    popd
)
```

The problem with this script is that it only runs from the same folder that it's in. Can this be altered to work on any path I specify, or is there another script that does so already?

EDIT: SOLVED! Turns out the solution was staring me in the face all the time. The script works from the current directory from where the batch file was run, as indicated by the "%CD%" variable. So all I had to do was to insert a line at the beginning to change the directory to the one I wanted, as I've indicated above with the arrows. Thanks for encouraging me to do some research and solve the problem myself! I used to be quite the programmer back in the day, glad I've still remembered a lot of stuff!

Comment: It probably can be altered, but, we're not here to do your work! What you need to do is give it a go yourself, and if it goes wrong, then please do ask and we're happy to help with specific issues :) Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1127039/edit) and show us what you've tried (instead of just copying and pasting some one else's code) and clearly explain why it doesn't work or any error message you get, then we can help :)

Comment: Glad to hear you worked it out! If you found a solution to your problem, you are encouraged to answer your own question. After some cooldown time, you can then selected your answer as the accepted answer.